# How to excplude module cxf-rt-transports-http

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have the following dependency in build.gradle:

```
compile ('org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:2.4.2')  {

        exclude module: 'log4j-over-slf4j'

    }
```

I would like to also exclude the module that contains transports-http because of a conflict between libraries (using HTTPConduit). I tried to exclude it, but I don't think I have the right module name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dependencies` task will give you a dependency report where you can see what transitive dependencies are being pulled in.

```
./gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath
```

If you were to examine the output of that task, you'll see that `org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle` does not appear to bring in `cxf-rt-transports-http`. So you'll need to examine your project to figure out where the duplicate dependency is.

Gradle also offers a means to handle version conflicts as well: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:resolving-version-conflict